# PXE + SystemRescueCD + AutoRun not working

Tags: linux, pxe

I'm trying to boot SystemRescueCD via PXE (which is working fine) but it somehow does not run my autorun script. Any idea why? This is what I use as `pxelinux.cfg/default`:

```
DEFAULT sysresccd
LABEL sysresccd
  LINUX sysresccd/boot/i686/vmlinuz
  INITRD sysresccd/boot/intel_ucode.img,sysresccd/boot/amd_ucode.img,sysresccd/boot/i686/sysresccd.img
  APPEND archisobasedir=sysresccd ip=dhcp archiso_http_srv=http://192.168.0.1:8181/ checksum docache ar_source=http://192.168.0.1:8181/ autoruns=no ar_nodel ar_wait
  SYSAPPEND 3
```

There is a http server running at 192.168.0.1:8181 serving up the `airoot.sfs` as well as a shell script named `autorun`.

Comment: Complete guess - maybe needs to be autorun.inf? Why have autoruns=no in the command line?

Comment: From the docs (https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/manual/Run_your_own_scripts_with_autorun/): "autoruns=[0-9]: comma separated list of the autorun scripts that have to be run. For instance if you use autoruns=0,2,7 then the following autorun scripts will be executed: autorun0, autorun2, autorun7. Use autoruns=no to disable all the autorun scripts with a number." .... "if a shell script named autorun is found, it is run" - so this is just the configuration for a single auto run

Comment: Do you have an access log for your http server? Does it show an attempt to get the autorun file?

Comment: no attempt unfortunately

Comment: Downgrading to SystemRescueCD 6.0.3 makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the newer versions of SystemRescueCD - downgrading to 6.0.3 makes it work.